# Prove $ \text{If }a_n \text{ is bounded and }b_n\rightarrow 0\text{ then }\lim_{x\to\infty}a_nb_n = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Can someone explain me, please, why:

$ \text{If }a_n \text{ is bounded and }b_n\rightarrow 0\text{ then }\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nb_n = 0$ ?

And a link to a proof on the web. I searched on the web but I really can't find that proof, or I don't know what to search.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830424/help-with-proving-if-s-n-converges-to-0-and-x-n-is-a-bounded-sequence-the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a_n$ is bounded, there is a positive real number $M$, such that $|a_k|\le M$ holds for all $k\ge 1$.

Hence, we have $|a_k\cdot b_k|\le M\cdot |b_k|$

Since $b_k$ tends to $0$, $|a_k\cdot b_k|$ also tends to $0$

Answer (score 2):

There exists $M \geq |b_n|$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, and since

$$-M a_n \leq a_nb_n \leq Ma_n,$$

we have by the squeeze principle, and basic limit calculations ($\lim_{n \to \infty} M a_n=M\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$), that $a_n b_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a_n)$ is bounded there exists $M$ such that $|a_n|\le M,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$

If $(b_n)\to 0$ then

$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: n\ge N\implies |b_n|<\epsilon.$$

Thus

$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: n\ge N\implies |a_nb_n|\le M|b_n|<M\epsilon.$$ In other words, $a_nb_n\to$ as $n\to \infty.$